# All possible combinations of variable R

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I have a list of variables and values for several subjects in a data frame (see below). I am using R/R Studio and would like to reformat the data to return every possible combination of variables, as well as their corresponding values for each subject. The actual dataset is much larger than this, so any way of doing it programmatically would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou

**My current data**

```
Variable Subject Value
  V1       A      1
  V1       B      0
  V1       C      1
  V2       A      0
  V2       B      1
  V2       C      0
  V3       A      1
  V3       B      1
  V3       C      1
```

**My desired output**:

```
Subject Variable 1     Variable 2      Value 1      Value 2
   A        V1              V2            1            0
   A        V1              V3            1            1
   A        V2              V3            0            1   
   B        V1              V2            0            1
   B        V1              V3            0            1
   B        V2              V3            1            1
   C        V1              V2            1            0
   C        V1              V3            1            1
   C        V2              V3            0            1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `combn` to create all possible combinations of `Variable` and `Value` columns for each `Subject`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

create_data_frame <- function(var, val) {
  tab1 <- setNames(data.frame(t(combn(var, 2))), paste0('Variable', 1:2))
  tab2 <- setNames(data.frame(t(combn(val, 2))), paste0('Value', 1:2))
  cbind(tab1, tab2)
}

df %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  summarise(data = list(create_data_frame(Variable, Value))) %>%
  unnest(col = data)

#  Subject Variable1 Variable2 Value1 Value2
#  <chr>   <chr>     <chr>      <int>  <int>
#1 A       V1        V2             1      0
#2 A       V1        V3             1      1
#3 A       V2        V3             0      1
#4 B       V1        V2             0      1
#5 B       V1        V3             0      1
#6 B       V2        V3             1      1
#7 C       V1        V2             1      0
#8 C       V1        V3             1      1
#9 C       V2        V3             0      1
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution, in R version 4.1.0 using native pipes

```r
df <- read.table(text = 'Variable Subject Value
  V1       A      1
  V1       B      0
  V1       C      1
  V2       A      0
  V2       B      1
  V2       C      0
  V3       A      1
  V3       B      1
  V3       C      1', header = T)


t(combn(unique(df$Variable), 2)) |> as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(c('Variable1', 'Variable2')) |>
  merge(df, by.x = 'Variable1', by.y = 'Variable') |>
  merge(df, by.x = c('Variable2', 'Subject'), by.y = c('Variable', 'Subject'), suffixes = c('1', '2'))

#>   Variable2 Subject Variable1 Value1 Value2
#> 1        V2       A        V1      1      0
#> 2        V2       B        V1      0      1
#> 3        V2       C        V1      1      0
#> 4        V3       A        V2      0      1
#> 5        V3       A        V1      1      1
#> 6        V3       B        V1      0      1
#> 7        V3       B        V2      1      1
#> 8        V3       C        V1      1      1
#> 9        V3       C        V2      0      1
```

check it with desired

```r
t(combn(unique(df$Variable), 2)) |> as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(c('Variable1', 'Variable2')) |>
  merge(df, by.x = 'Variable1', by.y = 'Variable') |>
  merge(df, by.x = c('Variable2', 'Subject'), by.y = c('Variable', 'Subject'), suffixes = c('1', '2')) -> df_new

df_new[order(df_new$Subject),c(2,3,1,4,5)]  
#>   Subject Variable1 Variable2 Value1 Value2
#> 1       A        V1        V2      1      0
#> 4       A        V2        V3      0      1
#> 5       A        V1        V3      1      1
#> 2       B        V1        V2      0      1
#> 6       B        V1        V3      0      1
#> 7       B        V2        V3      1      1
#> 3       C        V1        V2      1      0
#> 8       C        V1        V3      1      1
#> 9       C        V2        V3      0      1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Also works, but I cant mark both answers as the right one. But upvoted anyway. Thankyou for your help too :)

Comment: @thehand0 Glad to have been of help.  Accepting any answer is purely a personal choice, so no issues. :)